# Calling action on PartialView

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm new to MVC so I might not get the full idea of how to use actions in PartialViews so bear with me.

I have a PartialView with a form and I want to execute an action on the PartialView's controller when it is submitted. I have made this work, however, when I use

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div class="search-box">
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Keyword)
            <button type="submit" title="Search" id="searchButton">Search</button>
        </div>
    }
```

I don't get any parameters in the URL, and I would like people to be able to deeplink into this search. If I add the Action and Controller in my BeginForm tag, I get a URL looking like this: /LostItems/Index?Keyword=phones which returns a 404 because it's a PartialView and not a View that would have a routing.

How should I approach this issue? If the form was on a View and not a PartialView it would have worked just fine because the URL routes to that specific action on the page.

Comment: You cannot have just `BeginForm()`, you should specify the controller and action: `Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", ...)`. Most likely, the problem is in your action - can you post it as well? Also, you said that exactly the same HTML code works if put in a normal view - can you double check?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an action method return a partial view if you want to directly link to it as a full page (like /LostItems/Index?Keyword=phones )

If its a simple one-word search then no need to make a viewmodel class for that.

Im guessing what you should have is simply something like

```
//controller
public ActionResult Index(string Keyword)
{
    var SearchResults = new List<SearchResult>()

    //
    // Get your search results
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Keyword))
    {
        SearchResults = GetSearchResults(Keyword) 
             //your code for getting the search results
    }
    return View(SearchResults)
}
```

View:

```
@model List<SearchResult>
<h1>Search</h1>
@using(Html.BeginForm("Index", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.Label("Keyword", "Enter your Search Term")
    @Html.Texbox("Keyword")
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}

@if(Model.Count > 0)
{
   //display the search results - could be in a partial view, with the model passed though like
   @Html.Partial("_resultsGrid", Model)
}
```

That should work via a GET whether Keyword is specified or not I think, but I could be wrong (in which case a bit of routing is required to specify the default).

The alternative structure (especially for a more complex search) is to create a viewmodel for search terms, but dump the search results into the Viewbag instead of as a model (so the searchTerm can remain as the model, to be re-posted if it changes)